# Removing negative values from Set

Tags: java, loops, collections, iterator, set

*I expected remove() method removes negative values and prints only positive integers, but output is -1 -2 -3 4*

```
 import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class GenericSetTester {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Set<Integer> integerSet = new HashSet<>();

            integerSet.add(0);
            integerSet.add(1);
            integerSet.add(2);
            integerSet.add(3);
            integerSet.add(4);
            integerSet.add(-1);
            integerSet.add(-2);
            integerSet.add(-3);

            for(Iterator<Integer> in = integerSet.iterator(); in.hasNext();){
                if(in.next() < 0)
                    in.remove();
                   int i = in.next();
                System.out.printf("%d ",i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @Eran answer corrects your current approach.  Note that streams provide another way to handle your requirement:

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, -2, -3};
Set<Integer> integerSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array));
integerSet = integerSet.stream()
    .filter(i -> i >= 0)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Actually this is works too. 
`integerSet.stream().filter(a -> a > 0).forEach(System.out::println);`
For me was interesting what is going on inside loop.

Comment: Since the question and the loop example are about modifying the existing set rather than creating a new one, the simplest solution is `integerSet.removeIf(i -> i < 0);`. I have no idea why everyone tenaciously ignores the straight-forward Collection methods…

Answer (score 1):

This loop consumes two elements of the `Set` on each iteration (since you call `in.next()` twice in each iteration), which is wrong, and leads to the negative elements not being removed.

Consider the order in which the elements of your `Set` are iterated:

```
0 // consumed by if(in.next() < 0), which returns false, element not removed
-1 // consumed by int i = in.next();, and later printed -1
1 // consumed by if(in.next() < 0), which returns false, element not removed
-2 // consumed by int i = in.next();, and later printed -2
2 // consumed by if(in.next() < 0), which returns false, element not removed
-3 // consumed by int i = in.next();, and later printed -3
3 // consumed by if(in.next() < 0), which returns false, element not removed
4 // consumed by int i = in.next();, and later printed 4
```

As you can see, your loop doesn't remove any element from the `Set`, and prints only half of the elements (`-1 -2 -3 4`).

It should be:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> in = integerSet.iterator(); in.hasNext();) {
    int i = in.next();
    if (i < 0)
        in.remove();
    else
        System.out.printf("%d ",i);
}
```

As Tim suggested, if you print the `Set` after the loop, you'll see whether or not it contains only the elements it should contain. Your loop will become:

```
for(Iterator<Integer> in = integerSet.iterator(); in.hasNext();){
    if(in.next() < 0)
        in.remove();
}
System.out.println (integerSet);
```

Comment: Actually, I would print the list after the OP's for loop, to show that only non negative elements are left.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that would also work, but would result in the same output (since only negative elements are removed and only non-negative elements are printed)

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is the following:
The integerSet adds the numbers in this order (I don't know why though):
0: 0
1: -1
2: 1
3: -2
4: 2
5: -3
6: 3
7: 4

That why if you do the loop, it first checks if the next of 0 is smaller then 0. Which will return true since -1 is smaller dan 0. So 0 will be deleted. Then it check is the next of -1 which is 1, is smaller then 0. Which will return false. So -1 will not be removed.

That why the outpput is -1 -2 -3 4

Comment: `So 0 will be deleted` - no 0 is not deleted, it's just not printed. Actually, in the OP's code, nothing is deleted for the given input. If you print the Set after the loop is done, you'll see all the elements.

Comment: The order of a set is random and must not be relied on (per documentation). The current implementation iterates in the order of the hash values. But that changes per JDK version and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

*a lambda that retains the original* `Set`

```
integerSet.removeAll( integerSet.stream().filter( i -> i < 0 ).collect( Collectors.toList() ) );
…
```

*…or simple:* [Holger's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) solution – see comment below

```
integerSet.removeIf( i -> i < 0 );
```

Comment: This is clever, but wouldn't what you are passing to `removeAll` itself be a new set?

Comment: No – what is passed to `removeAll` is a `List` (more precisely an ArrayList). The point is, that the value of `integerSet` is not reassigned.

Comment: It’s not reassigning `integerSet`, but it’s unnecessarily creating a new collection for the sake of modifying the old one. Just use `integerSet.removeIf(i -> i < 0);` instead.